# character array initialisation to NULL in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, null, character

What is the difference between initialising character array as this

`char c[10]={0};`

and this

`char c[10]="";`

Comment: Consider using `std::string` for strings if possible. And `NULL` has a different meaning than `0`

Comment: which language? Tag says C++ and title says C...

Comment: @Timo: OP gets away with this by the skin of their teeth - answer is the same in either language.

Comment: @Bathsheba yeah but I don't know that because I don't know the C specification :P

Comment: @Timo: Does anyone? -;)

Comment: @Timo sorry for the confusion. It's cpp.I think its mostly same in c as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`char c[10]={0};` guarantees that every element of the array is 0. Note that in C++ you can write `char c[10]={};` which has the same effect.

`char c[10]="";` guarantees that **only** the first element of the array is 0; the other elements are uninitialised.

Comment: Is there a way to see the difference while printing?
`for (int i=0;i<10;i++){
 if(c[i]=='\0') printf("null char");
     printf("%c\n",c[i]); 
 }`
when I print this way both give same output

Comment: @PragatiSharma: That's the beauty of reading uninitialised `char` data: you don't know what you're going to get.

Comment: Okay, so be it.Thank you. :)